# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Well, I looked at all questions related to my problem in the forum, but I could not solve my problem. So I'm asking for help from anyone who can help me with my problem.

In case, everything was working without using the @Transactional annotation, however I want to make it work this way, waiting for comments.

This is my persistence.xml:

```
    <persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <!-- Persistence Unit -->
    <persistence-unit name="databaseEstoque" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <!-- Implements to JPA, in this case Hibernate -->
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <!-- Here you can see all entities -->
        <class>com.systemhaus.examples.domain.Produto</class>
        <class>com.systemhaus.examples.domain.Gaveta</class>
        <class>com.systemhaus.examples.domain.AbstractOperacao</class>
        <class>com.systemhaus.examples.domain.AdicionaQuantidade</class>
        <class>com.systemhaus.examples.domain.RetiraQuantidade</class>

        <properties>
            <!-- JDBC properties -->

            <!-- Hibernate specific settings -->
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

This is my applicationContext.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <bean id="myEmf"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="databaseEstoque" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />

    <bean id="gavetaDAO" class="com.systemhaus.examples.infraestructure.GavetaDBDAO" />

    <bean id="produtoDAO" class="com.systemhaus.examples.infraestructure.ProdutoDBDAO" />

    <bean id="operacaoDAO" class="com.systemhaus.examples.infraestructure.OperacaoDBDAO" />

    <bean id="notaFiscalDAO" class="com.systemhaus.examples.infraestructure.NotaFiscalDBDAO" />

    <bean id="compraFacade" class="com.systemhaus.examples.application.CompraFacade">
        <constructor-arg ref="produtoDAO" />
        <constructor-arg ref="gavetaDAO" />
        <constructor-arg ref="operacaoDAO" />
        <constructor-arg ref="estoque" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="vendaFacade" class="com.systemhaus.examples.application.VendaFacade">
        <constructor-arg ref="produtoDAO" />
        <constructor-arg ref="gavetaDAO" />
        <constructor-arg ref="operacaoDAO" />
        <constructor-arg ref="estoque" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="notaFiscalFacade" class="com.systemhaus.examples.domain.NotaFiscalFacade">
        <constructor-arg ref="produtoDAO" />
        <constructor-arg ref="gavetaDAO" />
        <constructor-arg ref="operacaoDAO" />
        <constructor-arg ref="notaFiscalDAO" />
        <constructor-arg ref="estoque" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="estoque" class="com.systemhaus.examples.domain.Estoque">
        <constructor-arg ref="estoqueRepositoryDB" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="estoqueRepositoryDB"
        class="com.systemhaus.examples.infraestructure.EstoqueRepositoryDB">
        <constructor-arg ref="gavetaDAO" />
        <constructor-arg ref="produtoDAO" />
        <constructor-arg ref="operacaoDAO" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:/home/pauloprass/eclipse-workspace/Java_Spring_Examples/lib/databaseEstoque" />
        <property name="username" value="Paulo" />
        <property name="password" value="1" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

And this is my method:

```
private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    @PersistenceUnit
    public void setEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        this.emf = emf;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void saveGaveta(Gaveta gaveta) {
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        em.persist(gaveta);
        em.flush();
    }
```

Comment: and what exactly is the problem ? could you try to be more specific and keep only the related code. Posting a wall of code isen't making it easier to understand

Comment: I was able to solve my problem, it happens that it was a first time I created a Maven project. So I had made the imports of the JARs that were in my lib, but I was using a pom.xml, and even if I was changing my pom.xml dependencies he was using the classes imported from my lib, well, mine solution was to clean up what was compiled and remove all JARS from the lib and add the dependencies in pom.xml.

Comment: if you solved your problem you should write it as an answer

Comment: Sorry dude, I'll do it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem, it happens that it was a first time I created a Maven project. So I had made the imports of the JARs that were in my lib, but I was using a pom.xml, and even if I was changing my pom.xml dependencies he was using the classes imported from my lib, well, mine solution was to clean up what was compiled and remove all JARS from the lib and add the dependencies in pom.xml.